# How can I access object(stdClass) In a blade view

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I am sending this to a view:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#336 (13) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["id_user"]=>
    NULL
    ["race"]=>
    string(7) "Mestizo"
    ["species"]=>
    string(6) "Canina"
    ["date_of_birth"]=>
    string(10) "2017-01-19"
    ["description"]=>
    string(54) "Un perrito muy bonito y pequeño que busca una familia"
    ["health"]=>
    string(8) "Muy bien"
    ["nickname"]=>
    string(6) "Tudels"
    ["place_found"]=>
    string(8) "Valencia"
    ["size"]=>
    string(7) "Mediano"
    ["date_found"]=>
    string(10) "2017-03-01"
    ["condition"]=>
    NULL
    ["url"]=>
    string(19) "/img/animals/1.jpeg"
  }
}
```

`animals` is the variable name in the view for the items above.
How can I access for example the ID in the blade view? I tried using `{{animals->id}}`, but it doesn't work

Comment: `{{ animals[0]->id }}`

Comment: Many thanks! I am trying to learn laravel and PHP so I have dumb errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `{{ animals[0]->id }}`

I think you have to learn PHP before, then you can try to code in Laravel.

So, some references on PHP basic array: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach ($result as $row)
{{$row->id}}

@endforeach
```